# Trim first string columns in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Got a string like: `AA BB CC DD EE` (space separated), how to remove `AA BB CC` first 3 columns in Obj-C in simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use regex `^([\S]+\s){3}|-`. don't forget to doubling the backslash character because it's in string `^([\\S]+\\s){3}|-`.

the `{3}` represent first 3 space characters (in this case, columns)

```
NSString *string = @"AA BB CC DD EE";
NSError *error = nil;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^([\\S]+\\s){3}|-"
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:&error];

NSString *result = [regex
                            stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string
                            options:0
                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                            withTemplate:@""];

NSLog(@"%@", result); // result : DD EE
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [`-[NSString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:) to split at whitespace. Then you could use [`-[NSArray subarrayWithRange:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/subarrayWithRange:).